# How to achieve inline flow for flexbox elements

Tags: flexbox

I have some `inline-block` elements that also need to be `flex` because i want their children to behave a certain way. Is there a way? Please do not suggest floating.

edit: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfbogutp/)
Honestly i just want to make a point. I know it doesn't work. Why do i have to tamper with an elements display property when my goal is not to change its own behavior? Only one of the reasons flex still sucks.

Comment: Your question is broad and unclear. Please describe the goal and provide the code you've tried. If you could provide a demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net) and an image illustrating what you want, that would be good, too.

Comment: A bit silly to blame the car when you are not able to drive. Ppl really do want to help, but you need to be clear on what you want, as the fiddle you gave works just fine with the `inline-block`. What we will not do is keep guessing until one answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```css
.container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: dashed 5px red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    
}
p{
    white-space: normal;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.child{
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    border: dashed 5px blue;
    flex:1 1 20%;
    display: flex; /* do not change this! */
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <p> i want my children next to each other...i wish i could just make them inline-block</p>
    <div class="child"><p>some fancy flexbox stuff going on in here</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>some fancy flexbox stuff going on in here</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>some fancy flexbox stuff going on in here</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>some fancy flexbox stuff going on in here</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well good try but no. You see what i want to achieve when you use inline-block instead of flex for the children. But i can't do that because the children have content that needs flex. I guess i should just add another wrapper solely for providing display flex. Not cool if you want to write half-decent semantical markup.